# NestJS testing that interception has been called on a controller

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I'm looking to see if there is a recommended way to write a JEST test that an *Interceptor* has been called. In the example below *LoggingInterceptor* was called? The purpose of test is verify that NestJS Binding interceptors is in place.

````
import { Controller, Get, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { LoggingInterceptor, TransformInterceptor } from './transform.interceptor';


@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
  @UseInterceptors(LoggingInterceptor)
  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would advise *against* testing that. Think about what you're testing: you're testing that the framework is doing what it says it will, something that the framework itself already tests. Sure you could use the `Reflect` API and verify that that metadata does exist, but that's something the framework should assert, it's a feature you should just be able to use with peace of mind.

Comment: In more a case to have a Jest test to verify that the Binding e.g `@UseInterceptors(TranformInterceptor)` was not removed from the Controller.

Comment: Just to verify that no one removes it or something?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Comment: If that's the case you can use the `Reflect` API to verify that the method has the metadata key `__interceptors__` and validate the metadata that is there.

Answer (score 0):

One option I used to create a Jest test to verify that a binding interceptor(Which transformed the response) on a controller was called and produced the expected response was by using NestJS *Supertest* lib to simulate an end to end test.

Related NestJS doc:

- List item

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing

Test Code Sample:

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { CatsModule } from '../../src/cats/cats.module';
import { CatsService } from '../../src/cats/cats.service';
import { CoreModule } from '../../src/core/core.module';

describe('Test interceptor response binding was triggerred', () => {
  const aServiceResponse = { findAll: () => ['test'] };
  const expectedResponseAfterTransformation = { code: 200, data: [ 'test' ] };

  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [CatsModule, CoreModule],
    })
      .overrideProvider(CatsService)
      .useValue(aServiceResponse)
      .compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it(`/GET cats returns transformed data respsone`, () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/cats').expect(200).expect({
      data: expectedResponseAfterTransformation,
    });
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```